# Reading and Printing User Entered MIPS Array

Tags: arrays, mips

So I am using MIPS trying to read in several strings entered by a user and then print them, but I am not getting the behavior I expect.

I want to take in 4 bytes of user input (4 characters essentially). In my loop I use the letter 'D' as a signal to exit. The problem is, no matter what I input, when I try to print the very first input later (or even the second, or the third), all I get printed out is the letter 'D' that was used to exit (which should be the last value of the array no?).

```
.data
 mem: .space 256 #256 bytes of space for input
 inst .space 5
.text 

la $s1, mem #s1 used to take input
la $s2, 0($s1) #Pointer to base address of memory

jal readLoop #Read input loop 

lw $a0, 0($s2) #Attempt to read very first saved input
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0, 10 #End program 
syscall

readLoop:

li $v0, 8 #read string
la $a0, inst #location of input memory
addi $a1, $zero, 5 #length of buffer
syscall

lb $t2,($a0) #used to exit loop

sw $a0, 0($s1) #store input into memory
addi $s1, $s1, 4 #increment memory by 4 bytes

li $t1, 'D'
bne $t2, $t1, readLoop #exit loop on input of a 'D'

jr $ra
```

I've checked my input as it comes in and even when in the array after saving. It seems my print is the problem, but I could easily be wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: are you programming in a text editor or an ide?

Comment: Programming is being done in Mars. Good point, sorry for forgetting that.

Comment: yea sometimes it can be the IDE and you can also use an IDE to look at the registers I think to see if the data is getting stored or if your logic is messed up.

Comment: That can't be the entire program. You're referring to a label `inst` that doesn't exist in the code you've shown us. In any case, you store the contents of every string that you read at the same location (`inst`), including the final string `"D"`, which then is what you'll end up printing.

Comment: Forgot to include the inst label at the beginning, but it is a simple memory space declaration. @Michael wouldn't the `sw $a0, 0($s1)` line save the contents of `inst` into `$s1`, the array of 256 bytes (declared by the label `mem`). Then, incrementing `$s1` by four should get the next space in the array right?

Answer (score 0):

The fix was rather easy. Instead of storing the user input into a separate memory location and then putting that location in my array, I simply had the user input be stored directly into my array. See code changes below.

```
.data
 mem: .space 256 #256 bytes of space for input
.text 

la $s1, mem #s1 used to take input

jal readLoop #Read input loop 

la $a0, mem #Attempt to read very first saved input
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0, 10 #End program 
syscall

readLoop:

li $v0, 8 #read string
la $a0, mem #set user input as memory location
addi $a1, $zero, 5 #length of buffer
syscall

lb $t2,($a0) #used to exit loop

addi $s1, $s1, 4 #increment memory by 4 bytes

li $t1, 'D'
bne $t2, $t1, readLoop #exit loop on input of a 'D'

jr $ra
```